# .htaccess mod_rewrite and Query Strings

Tags: .htaccess

In my .htaccess file I've got a rule that strips the .php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

So, **/mydomain.com/page.php** becomes **/mydomain.com/page/** - Which works fine.

Now I'm trying to achieve something similar with query strings, where:

**/mydomain.com/page.php?variable=value** becomes **/mydomain/page/value/**

I've tried numerous methods and the best I can get is **/mydomain/page/?variable=value**

Answer (score 1):

Your second rule is

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php`

You can change this to rewrite to a query param like this:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1.php?variable=$2`